# Remove the first n words from a text document in R

Tags: r, string, text, tidyverse

I have a problem in R and I don´t find a similiar solution in Stackoverflow.

I have a dataframe with a lot of different text documents. I tried gsub to remove some characters from a text document after a specific pattern. This works fine but now I have the problem that I would like to remove the first 5 words from every text document.

With the examples:

1. "Hey I am Tom and I like Bananas"
2. "Hey I am Moritz and I like Chocolate"

And the Solution should be:

1. "I like Bananas"
2. "I like Chocolate"

Is this with a specific function possible in R?
This would help me a lot.

Kind Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar option with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(s, '(\\w+\\s+){5}')
#[1] "I like Bananas"   "I like Chocolate"
```

#### data

```
s <- c("Hey I am Tom and I like Bananas", "Hey I am Moritz and I like Chocolate")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `gsub` like below

```
> gsub("(\\w+\\s+){5}", "", s)
[1] "I like Bananas"   "I like Chocolate"
```

**Data**

```
s <- c(
  "Hey I am Tom and I like Bananas",
  "Hey I am Moritz and I like Chocolate"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit`, `sapply`, and `paste`

```
xx <- c("Hey I am Tom and I like Bananas", "Hey I am Moritz and I like Chocolate")

sapply(strsplit(xx, split = " "),
       FUN = function(x) paste(x[6:length(x)], collapse = " "))

# [1] "I like Bananas"   "I like Chocolate"
```

Answer (score 0):

`stringr` option :

```
library(stringr)

s <- c("Hey I am Tom and I like Bananas", "Hey I am Moritz and I like Chocolate")
word(s, 6, str_count(s, '\\s')+1)
#[1] "I like Bananas"   "I like Chocolate"
```